# How to Add an onClick listener with a variable to a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a function call on a button through code. I was able to do this easily for my dropdown menu, but for some reason it isn't working for my buttons.
Here is my code:

```
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(onSpriteSheetChange(spriteSheet.Grass));
```

This code is giving me the error: cannot convert from 'void' to 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction'    Assembly-CSharp

Comment: I don't unity but I think you have a delegate type mismatch here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below snippet:

```
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => onSpriteSheetChange(spriteSheet.Grass));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Addlistener takes a UnityAction so if you put in a regular void method you will have this issue. As stated above you can put your call into a anonymous function using the lambda expression:

```
()=> method(attr);
// Or multiple lines using
()=>{
//code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onSpriteSheetChange won't return what you want you need to pass in

```
() => onSpriteSheetChange(spriteSheet.Grass)
```

as an argument to the AddListener so it knows which event and sprite sheet.

See:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html